# failed to create the java virtual machine

Tags: java, aptana

I have downloaded and installed aptana 3.0.6.

But when I try to start it up it comes with the message

> "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine".

Eclipse runs without problems. So, the Java Virtual Machine seems to run properly.
I am running on a 64-bits Windows 7.

Comment: It's really weird, afaik Aptana for windows comes with it's own JVM (%APTANA_INSTALL_DIR%\jre), have you tried executing the included java.exe? (%APTANA_INSTALL_DIR%\jre\bin\java.exe)

Comment: You may have 32-bit .exe file wich is Aptana runner. 32-bit process won't start 64-bit JVM. Try to make aptana run on 32-bit VM or try to run it in 64-bit mode.

Comment: can you post the contents of `aptana.ini` file

Answer (score 1):

This started happening to me after I tweaked Aptana performance. In my case main problem was that i putted Xmx1024m (instead od default 512 M) in my aptanastudio3.ini, but when i lowered it to Xmx768m everything started working.

Comment: This helped me. I changed 2 params in *AptanaStudio.ini* file: "-Xms768m
-Xmx768m" instead of "...1024m" as it was before. I know this is old, but it happened after Windows 10 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue with Aptana 3.6.0 on Windows 10
started happening after a windows update.
Java update didn't help

in AptanaStudio.ini file
commented out

```
-vmargs
```

that solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Aptana 3.6.0 on Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium. I ended up installing JRE 32-bit, and everything ran correctly.